# Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ehcache.CacheMangerBuilder

Tags: java, exception, ehcache

I'll preface this by saying "I have no idea what I'm doing" with java, let alone ehcache, but I'm trying to learn.

That said, I have this code I've written that ran fine until I added the ehcache stuff.  I had been simply writing to and reading from files, which worked fine but slow, so I'm trying to speed things up by using cache instead.

When I run my program, I get the following error, and I don't understand what it's telling me is wrong:

> Exception in thread "Connect thread - [6, 5]."
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ehcache.CacheManagerBuilder
> at com.ibm.tpf.internal.ZSTATEngine.doFilter(ZSTATEngine.java:24)
> at com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.FilterFramework.filterMessage(FilterFramework.java:229)
> at com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.APIFramework.addMessage(APIFramework.java:304)
> at com.ibm.tpf.etos.comm.ETOSConnection.addMessage(ETOSConnection.java:765)
> at com.ibm.tpf.etos.comm.ETOSModel._connect(ETOSModel.java:528)
> at com.ibm.tpf.etos.comm.ETOSModel$ConnectThread.run(ETOSModel.java:706)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org.ehcache.CacheMangerBuilder
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:496)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:631)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:597)
> ... 6 more

I tried to mimic the cache code found on the ehcache 3.0 documentation page... but I must've done something horribly wrong.  Anyone mind taking a look?

```
package com.ibm.tpf.internal;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.File;
import org.ehcache.*;
import org.ehcache.config.CacheConfigurationBuilder;

import com.ibm.tpf.etos.TPFFilter.*;
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.api.*;
import com.ibm.tpf.etos.filter.*;

public class ZSTATEngine implements ETOSFilterEngine {
    FilterFramework fw = null;
    String[] names = null;
        
    public ZSTATEngine(FilterFramework filFW, String[] parms) {
        super();
        this.fw = filFW;
    }
    
    public MessageBlock doFilter(MessageBlock msgBlock) throws FilterRuntimeException  {
        File file = new File("{path omitted}\\FILTER.DAT");
        CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder().withCache("csmpCache",CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder().buildConfig(Long.class, String.class)).build(false);
        cacheManager.init(); 
        Cache<Long, String> csmpCache = cacheManager.getCache("csmpCache", Long.class, String.class);
        if(msgBlock.getMsgID().equals("CSMP0097I")) {
            csmpCache.put(1L, msgBlock.getMsg()); /* 1L is a key */
            msgBlock.setSuppressed(TernarySwitch.ON);
        }
        else {
            if(msgBlock.getFlag() == Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG || msgBlock.getFlag() == Constants.ETOS_START_MSG) {
                if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
                    String csmpValue = csmpCache.get(1L);
                    MessageBlock mbCSMP = new MessageBlock(csmpValue, Constants.ETOS_ONE_MSG);
                    mbCSMP.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    msgBlock.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                    fw.addFilteredMessage(mbCSMP);
                }   
            }           
        }
        cacheManager.close();
        return msgBlock;                                             /* whatever gets returned is what the system prints */
    }

    private Color ColorStringInterpreter(String colorMsg) throws FilterRuntimeException {
        if (colorMsg.toUpperCase().startsWith("TOS")) {              /* if it starts with TOS, then we're using color names */
            String[] colorParts = colorMsg.split("_",2);
            String colorTxt     = colorParts[1].toString().trim();
            if (colorTxt.toUpperCase() != "NONE") {
                Color finalColor = Colors.fromString(colorTxt);
                return finalColor;
            }
        }
        else {
            String[] colorParts = colorMsg.split("_",3);            /* otherwise we're using RGB values */
            String sRed = colorParts[0].toString().trim();
            String sGreen = colorParts[1].toString().trim();
            String sBlue = colorParts[2].toString().trim();
            int iRed = Integer.parseInt(sRed);
            int iGreen = Integer.parseInt(sGreen);
            int iBlue = Integer.parseInt(sBlue);
            Color finalColor = new Color (iRed, iGreen, iBlue);
            return finalColor;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return null;
    }
    
    public void modifyState(Object[] newParams) throws FilterConfigurationException, FilterRuntimeException {
    }
    
    public boolean isActive() {
        return false;
    }
    
    public void shutdown() {
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Tell us which JAR files are in your project

Comment: I have added TOSApi_1.2.6.jar and ehcache-3.0.0.m3.jar

Comment: I downloaded the m3 from ehcache and had a look at it: the mentioned class definitely is contained in this jar. Are you sure you added the jar to your classpath ?

Comment: I'm sure of nothing since I'm such a noob, frankly, but I used the "add external jars" button?

Comment: This should work too, but (as you are not using maven or something similar) better create a lib folder in your eclipse project, copy all the jars you need here and add them directly from there using "Build Path / Add to Build Path"

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? If so, please share!

Comment: I did solve it, but sadly do not remember how.  It may have been the build path suggested by @Marged